# Queryset for current logged in user Django

Tags: django, django-views

I am doing queryset with my model. Now the queryset is displaying all the data in my html page. But I want to display only the logged in users data.

**models.py**

```
class Data(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
Date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def search(request):
    status_list = Data.objects.all()
    status_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=status_list)
    return render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_filter})
```

**filters.py**

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = {
        'Date': ['year','month', ], 'user': ['exact', ],
    }
```

I tried with different **views.py** also but it didn't work.

```
@login_required
def search(request, user):

    status_list = Data.objects.get(user=self.request.user).search(query)
    status_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=status_list)
    return render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_filter})
```

**data.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>

{% block content%}


      <form method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_table }}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
      </button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {% for user in filter.qs %}
        <li>{{ user.username }} - {{ user.get_full_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    <table id="datatable" style="margin-top: 20px" style="margin- 
    bottom:20px" class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>user</th>
        <th>EndDate</th>
        <th>Status</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for Data in filter.qs %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ Data.user }}</td>
          <td>{{ Data.EndDate }}</td>
          <td>{{ Data.Status }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% empty %}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">No data</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>


{% endblock content%}



  </body>
```

Above I added my HTML code also.Please look into html code also.

Comment: What is the `Data` model?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work". Explain how it didn't work. Is there an error message? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work fine.

```
 {% for data in filter %}
     <li>{{ data.user.username }} - {{ data.user.get_full_name }}</li>
 {% endfor %}

 {% for Data in filter %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ Data.user }}</td>
      <td>{{ Data.Date }}</td>
      <td>{{ Data.Status }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
```

As you would not be using filters, so filters.py should be removed.
This will also not work. Make the changes as required.
    {{ filter.form.as_table }}

Comment: hey i have one more query in that. could  you able to help me?

Comment: yes, tell me what it is :) Its time to sleep, I might reply tomorrow morning :P

Comment: in that html page i want to add search box or dropdown to filter month wise and year wise data. for example if logged in user selects November it should display November month data.

Comment: yeah no issues. when you get free time look into this

Comment: dropdown seems a better option as months have predefined names. Same goes for year also.

Comment: yeah okay. how to make that query?

Comment: because in my previous code i used filter.py to do that. now we removed that so it gone

Comment: when you get free time please look into that. Thanks in advance

Comment: pls check the last answer below.

Answer (score 3):

There could be better ways to do this. As you are still learning below code does the trick.

```
@login_required
def search(request, *args, **kwargs):
    status_list = Data.objects.get(user=request.user)

    month = request.GET.get("month", None)
    year = request.GET.get("year", None)

    if month:
        status_list = status_list.filter(Date__month=month)

    if year:
        status_list = status_list.filter(Date__year=year)

    return render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_list})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It shows the error.
TypeError:

'Data' object is not iterable 

        {% for user in filter %}

Comment: its not iterable means its not a list, it might be a single value of no value at all.

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: not iterable means you cant iterate over the object using a for loop. Check to see the value of filter using the code in the template. {{ filter }}. Does it show anything?

Comment: i added more data in table. i am getting error when i tried the above mentioned answer.          get() returned more than one Track -- it returned 3!

Comment: use filter() instead of get() status_list = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: i tried with {{ filter }}. in my html page it is showing like this        <QuerySet [<Track: Track object (2)>, <Track: Track object (6)>]>

Comment: i tried with this      status_list = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user) .    it shows the error ValueError: The view users.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: It cant be true, you are using the Data model, it cant show Track in anyway.

Comment: and the result?

Comment: i tried with this status_list = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user) . it shows the error ValueError: The view users.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: use return render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_list})
instead of render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_list})

Comment: it is displaying all the data for the users. it doesn't shows any search option for date or month wise

Comment: So you have to manually add the functionality for search, no? Add seperate select dropdown for months and years or have a seperate form and add two input fields one for month and one for year.

Comment: hey i got search box for year and month. i tried like this   
@login_required
def search(request, *args, **kwargs):
    status_list = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    status_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=status_list)
    return render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_filter})

Comment: i didnt get drop down but i got searchbox

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code, django provides many helpers function to help to programmer.

in your **views.py** you can do:

```
@login_required
def search(request):
    status_list = Data.objects.all()
    status_filter = status_list.filter(user=request.user) //get current user id
    return render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_filter})
```

Comment: if you need convert datetime (month, year) in template, you can use default filter dajngo date: `{{ field|date:"Y-m-d" }}`

Comment: Why would you want to first fetch all the entries in database then filter the ones of the current user?? isn't it a two step process ??

Comment: `status_list = Data.objects.all()` first proccess - all global data, `status_filter = status_list.filter(user=request.user)` second process - all data specific user. And you still have **status_list** as default data user, you can for example use it in other variables

Comment: Yes, you are right. if it is required to use the same orm query and apply some other filter ALSO, then only it makes sense to make it a two step process. Otherwise, filtering in the one orm query makes more sense.

Comment: hi thanks for your time. i tried with this code also. Previously with my code it display all the Users data.But now it didn't display any data. Any other possible solution?

Comment: put your actual code, please! and verify if user is logged

Answer (score 2):

```
status_list = Data.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

is wrong as self is only used in class based views. No wonder it did not work.
Please try with the below code instead

```
status_list = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user) or 
status_list = Data.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

So, the final code will be like

```
@login_required
def search(request):
    status_list = Data.objects.get(user=request.user)
    render(request, 'users/data.html', {'filter': status_list})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I tried with this code but it didn't display any data in my html page.

Comment: Are you using the right variable name to iterate over in the html template?? in this case the name is filter. Also, you have to make sure that there are some entries in the database for the table named Data for the current logged in user.

Comment: Check for the pk of the currently logged in user. Paste below code inside the function above. print(request.user.pk). You could also use below code. print(request.user.id). Then check in the database table Data, if any entries are associated with the value of pk or id.

Comment: {{ user.username }} i used this to print my logged in user name in html page. it is printing username correctly